# How to scrape a page for certain strings from an array of substrings with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, watir

I want to scrape a restaurant page for certain titles of dishes.
I created an array holding keywords:

```
myarray = {"Rice", "Soup", "Chicken", "Vegetables"}
```

Whenever one of those keywords is found in a webpage, my scraper is supposed to give me the entire dish-title. I made this work with the following code:

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)


word = html_doc.at(':contains("Rice"):not(:has(:contains("Rice")))').text.strip
puts word
```

For example this returns: "Dish 41 - Vegetables with Chicken and Rice"

The problem is that the above code stops after the first dish is found. It does not loop through all dish-titles containing the word rice. 
Secondly, I do not know how to let the code check for an entire array of substrings.

Comment: try `words = html_doc.css(':contains("Rice"):not(:has(:contains("Rice")))').map(&:text)` ?

Comment: `myarray = {"Rice", "Soup", "Chicken", "Vegetables"}` isn't an array.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the smallest HTML that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `css`. This will find all the elements which matches the given CSS and give you the collection:

```
words = html_doc.css(':contains("Rice"):not(:has(:contains("Rice")))').map(&:text)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the first part of my question!

Comment: I'm not sure I would trust Nokogiri with that css. I would trust jQuery though.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the second part of my question myself with this:

```
word = html_doc.css(":contains('#{keyword}'):not(:has(:contains('#{keyword}')))").map(&:text)
```

Comment: Your answer is based on @kiddorails answer. Please don't add answers like this. "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)".